# How to check if form is visible (WebDriver)?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have two forms:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" target="_self">
///
</form>

<style>
form#form2 {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<form action="" method="get" name="form2" id="form2" target="_blank">
////
</form>
```

And I have the following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("form"));
for (WebElement form : forms) { 
   if (!form.isDisplayed()) break;
   System.out.print(form.ToString() + "\n");
}
```

In the console, I see:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" target="_self">
<form action="" method="get" name="form2" id="form2" target="_blank">
```

How to check if form is invisible?

**The solution of the problem.**

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(**true**);
```

Comment: Will that css apply correctly ? Just check if that needs to be `form#form2`?

Comment: @NoobUnChained, I'm sorry for the typo, I corrected.

Comment: Did that solve your problem ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained,Unfortunately, no.

Comment: This might be irrelevant to you but , can you enclose the form in a <div> and try to apply the css to the <div> ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained, I did it. Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the real rendered html got from developer tool, if so, could you please paste that?

Give this a try, code not tested, the idea is if selenium thinks all forms are displayed, then we should try to get the css value or the value of style attribute for the forms, see how they are actually rendered. (I would suspect the selenium part you have done is correct, but the html styling is wrong.)

```java
// following your logic
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("form"));
for (WebElement form : forms) { 
   if (form.getCssValue("display") == "none") break;
   // or if (form.getAttribute("style").contains("display: none")) break;
   System.out.print(form.ToString() + "\n");
}

// a version showing more info
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("form"));
for (WebElement form : forms) {
   System.out.print(form.ToString() + "\n");
   System.out.print(form.isDisplayed() + "\n"); // how selenium determines
   System.out.print(form.getCssValue("display") + "\n"); // get css display value
   System.out.print(form.getAttribute("style") + "\n"); // get all style values if exists
   System.out.print("==================\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem. It was that javascript been disabled by default. When I put your code, I saw an exception (Javascript is not enabled for this HtmlUnitDriver instance).